# making a parameter in one page appear in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've two pages as shown in screen shots:
[image: img1]
[image: img2]
`HTML`

```
<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/angelic - Copy - Copy - Copy (2).png" id="angelic" /> <span>Angelic</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/angry - Copy - Copy - Copy.png" id="angry" /> <span>Angry</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/anxious - Copy - Copy - Copy.png" id="anxious" /> <span>Anxious</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/assertive - Copy - Copy.png" id="asserive" /> <span>Assertive</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/bored - Copy - Copy.png" id="bored" /> <span>Bored</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/confident - Copy - Copy.png" id="confident" /> <span>Confident</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/cranky - Copy - Copy.png" id="cranky" /> <span>Cranky</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/depressed - Copy - Copy.png" id="depressed" /> <span>Depressed</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/dissapointed - Copy - Copy.png" id="disappointed" /> <span>Dissapointed</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/distrustful - Copy - Copy.png" id="distrustful" /> <span>Distrustful</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/embarrassed - Copy.png" id="embarassed" /> <span>Embarrassed</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/emotional - Copy.png" id="emotional" /> <span>Emotional</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/evil - Copy.png" id="evil" /> <span>Evil</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/excited - Copy.png" id="excited" /> <span>Excited</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/exhusted.png" id="exhausted" /> <span>Exhusted</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/flirtatious.png" id="flirt" /> <span>flirtatious</span>

</div>

<div class="sm_img">

    <img src="img/forgetful.png" id="forget" /> <span>forgetful</span>

</div>
```

'Javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveSmileys() {
        /* var a = document.getElementById("angelic");
        var b = document.getElementById("angry");
        var c = document.getElementById("anxious");
        var d = document.getElementById("assertive");
        var e = document.getElementById("bored");
        var f = document.getElementById("confident");
        var g = document.getElementById("cranky");
        var h = document.getElementById("depressed");
        var i = document.getElementById("disappointed");
        var j = document.getElementById("distrustful");
        var k = document.getElementById("emotional");
        var l = document.getElementById("evil");
        var m = document.getElementById("excited");
        var n = document.getElementById("exhausted");
        var o = document.getElementById("flirt");
        var p = document.getElementById("forget");
 */
        /* if (a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k & l & m & n & o
                & p == true) { */

/*          var ang = parseInt(a);
            var an = parseInt(b);
            var anx = parseInt(c);
            var asse = parseInt(d);
            var bo = parseInt(e);
            var co = parseInt(f);
            var cr = parseInt(g);
            var de = parseInt(h);
            var dis = parseInt(i);
            var distr = parseInt(j);
            var em = parseInt(k);
            var ev = parseInt(l);
            var ex = parseInt(m);
            var exh = parseInt(n);
            var fl = parseInt(o);
            var fo = parseInt(p); */

            $(function() {
                $("#savesmiley").bind(
                        "click",
                        function() {
                            var url = "notes.html?Angelic="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#angelic").val())
                                    + "&Angry="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#angry").val())
                                    + "&Anxious="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#anxious").val())
                                    + "&Assertive="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#assertive").val())
                                    + "&Bored="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#bored").val())
                                    + "&Confident="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#confident").val())
                                    + "&Cranky="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#cranky").val())
                                    + "&Depressed="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#depressed").val())
                                    + "&Disappointed="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#disappointed").val())
                                    + "&Distrustful="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#distrustful").val())
                                    + "&Embarassed="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#embarassed").val())
                                    + "&Emotional="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#emotional").val())
                                    + "&Evil="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#evil").val())
                                    + "&Excited="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#excited").val())
                                    + "&Exhausted="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#exhausted").val())
                                    + "&Flirtatious="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#flirt").val())
                                    + "&Forgetful="
                                    + encodeURIComponent($("#forget").val());
                            window.location.href = url;
                        });
            });


        var QueryString = function() {

            var query_string = {};
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i = vars.length; i++) {

                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {

                    query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];

                } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {

                    var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
                    query_string[pair[0]] = arr;

                } else {

                    query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);

                }

            }

            console.log(query_string[pair[i]]);

        }
        alert("Moods have been saved");
    }
</script>
```

`HTML ( Notes page )`:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 38px;">Date:</div>

        <div style="position: absolute; right: 16px; top: 12px;">
            <input type=date id="dte">
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 55px; left: 36px;">Flow:</div>

        <div class="starbox ghosting autoupdate"
            style="position: absolute; right: 16px; top: 46px;" id="star"></div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 91px; left: 10px;">Period
            Ends Today!</div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="checkone"
            style="position: absolute; right: 40px; top: 90px;">

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 131px; left: 33px;">Note:</div>

        <div style="position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 126px;">
            <textarea id="note" id="nte"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 174px; left: 20px;">Medicine:</div>
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 173px;">
            <input type="text" id="med">
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 211px; left: 20px;">Symptoms:</div>
        <div>
            <a href="symptoms.html"><img src="./img/arrow.jpg"
                style="position: absolute; height: 40px; top: 197px; right: 10px;"></a>
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 247px; left: 30px;">Moods</div>
        <div>
            <a href="smiley.html"><img src="./img/arrow.jpg"
                style="position: absolute; height: 40px; right: 10px; top: 234px;"></a>
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 282px; left: 18px;">Intercourse</div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="checktwo"
            style="position: absolute; top: 283px; right: 40px;">

        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 64px; left: 26px;">Weight:</div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 318px; left: 155px;">
            <input type="text" id="wgt"
                style="right: -138px; position: absolute;"
                placeholder="Wieght in Kg or lb">
        </div>
        <!-- <div style="position: absolute; right: 30px; bottom: 94px;">
            <select>
                <option value="kg">Kg</option>
                <option value="lb">lb</option>
            </select>
        </div> -->

        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 35px; left: 11px;">Temparature:</div>
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 54px; left: 155px;">
            <input type="text" id="wgt1"
                style="right: -138px; position: absolute;"
                placeholder="Temparature in &#x2103; or &#x2109;">
        </div>
        <!-- <div style="position: absolute; right: 30px; bottom: 53px;">
            <select>
                <option value="centigrade">&#x2103;</option>
                <option value="faranheit">&#x2109;</option>
            </select>
        </div> -->
```

My problem is: If `Assertive` mood is selected and is saved, then it ( Assertive, i.e., the name of the selected mood ) should appear beside `Moods` in notes page.  How can I do it? Above javascript isn't working.

Comment: You need to show what the code is for the settings page..

Comment: how else could we know where the selected mood value should appear ?

Comment: It should appear beside Moods in notes page.... Do you see Moods and an arrow head in notes page? If assertive mood is selected in moods page, then it should appear beside Moods in notes page...

Comment: the code of the notes page is what i mean (*html/js*)..

Comment: Okay, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Where are you? Got any solution?

Comment: Can't post a solution with the current info. Just a suggestion: add a readonly `input` next to the `Mood` title (*like you do with the other options*) and when loading the page read the querystring (*i think that is where you put the selected moods*) and set the inputs' value

Comment: Tell me that what info do you need... I'll post all info that you need.

Comment: can you post a live version of your pages (*perhaps on http://plnkr.co*)?

Comment: Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/41vgJ3Llho7z9GSGMFK9?p=preview

Comment: Your moods are not being saved anywhere.. You can't even select any of them. Then you are using the `.val()` of each `img` which will not work. The `.val()` function is only for form input elements. The other page has no clue which smiley you selected.

Comment: Well, how can I fix it?